# setTimeout timer event

Tags: javascript, timer

```
function waitForThreeSeconds(){
    setTimeOut(function(){
       console.log('Time done');
    },3000);
}

waitForThreeSeconds();
console.log('finished execution');
```

In the code above, when the waitForThreeSeconds function is invoked an event is placed on the event queue for the setTimeout method. My question is when the waitForThreeSeconds function is invoked, will the three second timer in the function expression passed into setTimeout start immediately when the JS engine encounters the setTimeout method? Or will an event be placed on the event queue. Then after console.log("finished execution') line of code is run in the global execution context (which means everything is done executing in the JS file), then the three second timer will start and the callback function passed to setTimeout will run.

I am not sure when the timer in the setTimeout function actually starts. Would it start exactly when the JS engine encounters the setTimeout method or will the three second timer start when the JS engine goes to the event queue to process the event placed by the setTimeout method?

Comment: When function gets called, it is placed on the top of the `stack` hence in your terms, **immediately** is right!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/unrfgtcc/1/

Comment: So technically while the rest of the code is running, the timer is still running. Correct?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as we should already know, JavaScript is not a multi-threaded language, and is therefore a single-threaded language, although you can add events, terminate events, and even invoke events.

When creating an event, you add the event token on top of the queue, therefore it will be the last event to be recognized.

In your code, here is what happens:

`waitForThreeSeconds()`:
calls wait for three seconds

calls `setTimeout([...], 3000)`:
adds event as last token in event queue

at this point your event queue should look like:
[this.event, that.event, all.otherEvents, `ECMA.TimeStamp(3000)`]

The TimeStamp(3000) is the way we will represent the timer...

So every 1/1000 of a second (abstractly) the JS Engine will check the event queue for events which have been invoked. When it recognizes that `TimeStamp(3000)` has been invoked (after 3000 milliseconds) it will now invoke the callback function.

The weird part is that when you say `setTimeout([...], 3000)`, the JS engine adds the callback to the event queue, and moves on from there. It will not wait the 3 seconds to move on to the next line of code.

So as soon as you call `setTimeout()`, it will start the timer. So if it takes 2000 milliseconds to run the rest of your code, then 1000 milliseconds later your callback will be called... =)

### If you have any questions, please leave a comment!

Comment: Ahh, now this finally makes sense! That last example you provided cleared up my issue completely! Thank you!!

Comment: One quick comment: The time that is passed to the setTimeout method is simply a minimum time to wait right? The callback can be called even after 3000 ms. This can happen if it takes 4000 ms to run the rest of the code for example. Correct?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the JS engine polls the queue every ms for timer events as this is enormously inefficient in terms of both CPU usage and battery life.  Every OS supports timer events or timer notifications which require no CPU and almost no battery until the actual timer fires.  That's how Javascript does timer events.  It uses OS services for timers.

Comment: Answering Clay Horder's question: Even if it takes 4000ms to run the rest of the program, then the callback will still be called within 3000ms, meaning that the callback will be called, then 1000ms later the program will finish running

Comment: And in response to jfriend00, you are completely correct, but although JS uses the systems utilities for time, it still needs to check for that information very often. So JS will go back to the event queue, and request the system's date and time to see whether or not it should initiate the callback. Now although checking for events every 1ms is inefficient, that was just to be used as an example, not as an actual representation.

Comment: @VirajShah So basically at any point after 3000 ms the callback will be called even if there is code in the JS file that is still running? So the code in the JS will stop and the callback will be invoked and then the rest of the code continuing from it stopped will continue? Since I originally thought that JavaScript will never pause in the middle of a function to run another function because an event has fired.

Comment: Also if you have a for loop that creates three calls to the setTimeout method and each of those callbacks of setTimeout prints "Time Done". Does this mean that when JS engine hits each setTimeOut method in the for loop a separate 3 second timer for each setTimeout will start? Since when I ran the code it only waited for three seconds ONCE and printed out "Time Done" It didn't wait three seconds per timer and print out "Time Done".

Comment: Answering your first question: Remember that although JavaScript has strict rules about not stopping in the middle of a function to do something else... the `setTimeout()` is a primitive function, so it will communicate directly with the browser... The browser, and the engine are allowed to break certain rules

Comment: For your second problem: if you open up your console, and look again, on the right hand side of the `console.log()` message, you will see a red circle with a number inside of it... Browser do this, because if a webpage is using `Console.log()` to `log` the same message multiple times, it may be spam, so instead of logging the same message many times, it just puts a red bubble with a number inside it, to indicate that it has been called upon several times!

Comment: Oh ok! I was not aware the JS engine will stop execution and call the callback of the setTimout function even if it is in a middle of a function! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout`  is added to the mission of the end of the "task queue":

```
function waitForThreeSeconds(){
setTimeout(function(){
   console.log('Time done');
},0);} waitForThreeSeconds();console.log('finished execution');
```